How can SFTs be done only with the token22 program
I'm new to Solana and I don't really understand much..., so please bear with me.
With the metadata and metadata pointer on token22... I'm also aware of a metadata interface that could be on the mint(I thinks).
Here is my question;
Without metaplex, without pointing to a metaplex account whose token standard has been set to "FungibleAssets" (SFTs) with the metadata pointer; is it possible to have an SFTs with the metadata interface alone? What am saying is, are SFTs only possible with metaplex?
If it's doable without metaplex, what would I be lossing?
Thanks.
